# Half deflection in a galvanometer

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance

Why is half deflection taken while measuring the resistance of a galvanometer? Can't we take deflection in other ratios? Please help.

I meant to ask while taking out the shunt resistance, why do we always apply that amount of resistance which brings about half deflection? Why not quarter deflection or so?

Comment: Who says that's what's done and that's the only measurement?  What do you know about galvanometers?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I was reading about internal resistance of a galvanometer. In the book it was mentioned that it was found by half deflection method. There was no explanation for why only half deflection is chosen. Talking about galvanometers, I know very few about them. I know that they can be used as ammeters and voltmeters with appropriate shunting.

Comment: The question is indeed improved but it is not quite clear enough. Providing a link to a specific procedure, and quoting the steps which confuse you, will help make this question answerable.

Answer (score 2):

You set up a circuit which contains the galvanometer and adjust the circuit so that the deflection on the galvanometer is a maximum (for greatest accuracy).
A calibrated resistance box is connected in parallel and adjusted until the deflection on the galvanometer is half of the deflection with no resistance box.  In this condition the resistance of the resistance box (known) is equal to the resistance of the galvanometer.